# System.UnauthorizedAccessException when launch application by link

Tags: c#, windows, permissions

i've been wrote an application (C#, VS2013), and add installation to it (flexera).
Installation process provide copy files to ProgramFiles direcotiry and create a shortcut(link)  on desktop.
So, when i click on shortcut - program doesn't start, and in windows event log i see those exceptions:

> Сведения об исключении: System.UnauthorizedAccessException Стек:    в
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32, System.String)    в
>   System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(System.String,
>   System.String, System.Object, Boolean)    в
>   System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(System.String,
>   Boolean)    в main_windows.Settings.Log(System.String)    в
>   main_windows.Settings..ctor()    в main_windows.Program.Main()

if i start shortcut as administrator - everything fine.

at that time, if i go to folder with installed program and click on exe-file - it starts and there is not need to start it as admin.

I try different ways to solve this, by changing permissions to folder and file, including switch off/on inheritance, but unsusccessfull...

Question - What can i do, to solve my problem.

Comment: I think this has something to do with the working directory of the application. Can you please right click the icon on the desktop and see the folder specified in the "Start in" text box? When you start your program from the installation folder, the working directory will be that folder itself thus your application will work.

Comment: Working directory is correct(equal installation folder), i check it at first.

Comment: What is the Settings class?

Comment: Becuse it is trying to log something during start-up. Can you please post the code of your main_windows.Program.Main() method?

Comment: yes it's try. in main i got mutex for check application allready running. and some files operation there too. code is nt under hand - later ill post it. I think it doesn't mean matter - because as admin and from "release" running haven't trouble.

Comment: Can you please send the code for Settings class? It's Log method causes this exception.

Comment: I find a reason - to ProgramFiles there is no "full access" from user. and as i see - there is no way to open it

Comment: But you said running the program from inside the installation folder without administrative rights work.

Comment: i copy exe just in programfiles and click it - start fails

Comment: Of course. You should have your log files somewhere else. In fact, AppData folder or %TEMP% folder can be used for that, or during installation, under your installation directory, create the "logs" folder and grant full access to that folder to the current user

Comment: By the way, my second comment seems to have had addressed the issue, because in the stack trace it is obvious that the Settings.Log causes this exception

Comment: yes, i create "test" folder in programfiles(with admin permission) copy my exe file to this folder(with admin). then i change owner of test folder to self, and share "full access" for self. Only after that my exe start's ok by link without exceptions. Installer i use do not offer to do all those operations :)

Comment: i was try to comment my "Log" function - exception still appear :)

Comment: I am entering an answer, I would be glad if you can mark it as answer if it helps you having your log files in the appdata folder instead of the program files folder. Is that OK with you?

Comment: What is the stack trace of the exception you get after commenting out the Log() ?

Comment: from exception message disappear only words about log :)

Comment: Is CreateDirectory there? Can you paste it?

Comment: if you really want to know this - i can post exception message without log later.

Comment: I just want to know if your problem is solved or not..

Comment: cant find how to send you private message, if under "mark" you mean tick left from post with log code - it write i can check it after 2 days

Comment: I find a reason, and i think this mean  problem solved :) thx for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void Log(string s)
{

    string file = Application.ExecutablePath.Substring(0, Application.ExecutablePath.LastIndexOf('\\'));
    file += "\\logs\\";
    if (!Directory.Exists(file))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(file);
    file += DateTime.Now.Date.Year.ToString();
    file += "-" + DateTime.Now.Date.Month.ToString();
    file += "-" + DateTime.Now.Date.Day.ToString();
    file += (".log");
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Append);
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);

    sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString("00")+ ":" +
                 DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString("00") + ":" +
                 DateTime.Now.Second.ToString("00") + " " + s);
    sw.Close();
    fs.Close();
}
```

Comment: You are trying to create a directory under Program Files\YourCompany\YourSoftware\logs, which would fail, yes.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace main_windows
{

    static class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            bool createdNew = true;
            using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "Settings", out createdNew))
            {
                if (createdNew)
                {
                    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                    Application.Run(new Settings());
                }
                else
                {
                    Process current = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
                    foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName(current.ProcessName))
                    {
                        if (process.Id != current.Id)
                        {
                            SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);
                            break;
                        }
                    }


                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```